# Last doesn't work with default order in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following code in my Single model:
default_scope order("created_at ASC")

When I call

Single.where("user_id = ? ", dan).last(2)

I get:
SELECT "singles".* FROM "singles" WHERE (user_id = 22 ) ORDER BY created_at ASC, id DESC LIMIT 2

Instead of the DESC being applied to created_by it gets applied to id.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override default scope. That's why it adds to the order clause

You can do

```
Single.unscoped.order('created_at desc').where("user_id=?", 'dan').last(2)
```

I would advise you to not use `default_scope` and use a normal `scope`(default scopes are considered evil). So you don't forget that there is a default scope that is ordering by `created_at`

Also reading [this](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil) would give you some better understanding